# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type for a struct called within a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, queue, dereference

Looking at a lot of other similar questions, they don't seem to solve this issue of a struct being called within a struct.

I have a simple queue.c file which has several structs like struct Node, struct Queue, struct Queue* newQueue(int cap) etc...

here are the two relevant structs for this question inside the file **job_queue.c**:

```
...
struct Queue {
    int size;
    int max_size;
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
};

struct Queue* newQueue(int capacity)
{
    struct Queue *q;
    q = malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));

    if (q == NULL) {
        return q;
    }

    q->size = 0;
    q->max_size = capacity;
    q->head = NULL;
    q->tail = NULL;

    return q;
}
...
```

Here is the queue.h header file which I import into my main file.

```
#ifndef __SIMPLE_QUEUE__
#define __SIMPLE_QUEUE__

struct Queue;

extern struct Queue*
newQueue(int capacity);

extern int
enqueue(struct Queue *q, char* value);

extern void*
dequeue(struct Queue *q);

extern void
freeQueue(struct Queue *q);

#endif
```

I clearly define the names for the structs as guided by the other posts. In my main C file, I initialize the queue from the following

```
struct Queue* job_queue = newQueue(queue_cap);
```

I pass it to another function with the paramaters as follows:

```
void queueing(struct Queue* jobs_queue){
   ...
}
```

Within this function, I am trying to print the max_value by doing the following:

```
printf("Queue size: %d", jobs_queue->max_size);
```

However, I get the error: `dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct Queue'`

What do I have to fix to get rid of this error?

Comment: Is `queueing` is the queue.c file?  If not, it can't see the definition. So put the definition in a header file and include where necessary.

Comment: @dbush I import the queue.h file which references struct Queue and its extern functions etc. I will add this to the question too.

Comment: You need to define a function in `job_queue.c` that returns the value of the `max_size` element of the structure.  No other file knows the details of `struct Queue` so only that file can give that access.  Of course, the function should be declared in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queue.h file only *declares* `struct Queue`.  It doesn't *define* it, so files other than queue.c don't see the definition.

You need to put the full definition of the struct in queue.h for it to be seen in other files.

Comment: Doesn't that make the job_queue.c file redundant then? Like I have my structs definitions inside job_queue.c where I import queue.h. Them inside queue.h, I declare struct Queue and its methods. Then inside my main .c file, I import queue.h

Comment: @Infiniteon main.c only sees `struct Queue;` so it doesn't know what it contains.  The struct definition must go in the header file.  The other functions can still live in job_queue.c.